# Commitment - What do I need to do?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

Is there any reference other than the original text one receives when committing to a project on Area51 that one can see what is expected of them?

If not, what is required once committing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see the text again by clicking the commit link (but not confirming) on any other proposal. Here it is for reference:

> I commit to participate actively in (insert name here), to visit at least three times per week, to ask at least three questions during the beta phase, and to answer as many questions as I can for at least three months.

Comment: I would upvote but I like that reputation of yours :)

Comment: you are cursed to be at this rep for all eternity