# Where can I follow my commitments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, user-interface, commitment

Area51 frequently refers to your commitment, and how many people fulfilled it, and that you haven't yet but if you will, you will be able to commit again... However, **I found [only one way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55508/commitment-what-do-i-need-to-do) to re-read what it means to fulfill your commitment**: by going to another proposal in the commitment stage, clicking on the Commit button, reading what it says, and clicking cancel. Not very intuitive, if you ask me. [The faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) is also vague: "Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site."

Would it be possible to repeat this on your user page, maybe even with a progress bar for your own commitment, and certainly in the mails that are sent to users at the start of the private beta and after a few weeks? Currently users only get information that they should do *something*, but not what this *something* is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are intentionally vague: we don't want people gaming the fulfillment metrics.

So [the Area 51 faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) is canonical here, and already correct.

Not reaching commitment? Ask and answer a few more questions, then! :)

Comment: OK, I understand being vague and tweaking the parameters, but maybe the mail I just got (after 14 days) could contain a like like "You committed to this proposal, but we haven't seen as much activity from you (asking and answering questions) as we hoped. You are part of the founders of this community, so it's up to you to make it grow." I see the idea of the second sentence in the mail, but not the first.

Comment: @jan I like the 2nd sentence of your suggestion "You're one of the site founders; the community is counting on you lead the way and help the site grow."