# Check commitment status?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, commitment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I follow my commitments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59725/where-can-i-follow-my-commitments)

How can can I find out how much of my commitment I've fufilled on a SE2.0 site?  This normally isn't hard, as I can just count my questions and answers.  However on a converted site I need to know which posts count toward my commitment and don't.